# curl command unable to read variables when used in shell script throws error curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

Tags: bash, curl

unable to pass values to curl command using shell variable

```
curl -F 'file=@/root/bin/"$VARIABLE"' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/
```

The error says

```
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
```

Comment: the single quotes override the embedded double quotes so the variable reference (`$VARIABLE`) is not being replaced with the variable's actual value, ie, `curl` sees the literal string `"$VARIABLE"`; try replacing the single quotes with double quotes, eg: `curl -F "file=@/root/bin/$VARIABLE" http:...`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with

```
curl -F "file=@/root/bin/$VARIABLE" http://localhost:8000/api/v1
```

Also verify that the user has the correct permission of reading for this file.

If you want to know what it is happening, use "-v" argument in curl.